# Adding markers to a jQuery progressbar with countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I was looking at making a progressbar out of jQuery.  I want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/codekmarv/FXnjb/29/)  or something simpler like this code:

```
var bar = document.getElementById('progress'),
time = 0, max = 5,
int = setInterval(function() {
    bar.style.width = Math.floor(100 * time++ / max) + '%';
    time - 1 == max && clearInterval(int);
}, 1000);
```

However I also want the ability to add makers based on data.  By markers I mean something like [this](https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/1685857/1153387/81e47276-1f20-11e3-9966-324fa1524f9d.png) So say it is a 30 minute countdown and based on user input I need a marker to be placed at 15 minutes.

I would think this is possible, but I have no idea how to go about doing it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

This is what I have right now.  I'm new to javascript and jQuery so I might have something really wrong.  Right now I'm just simply trying to add a bar anywhere then later I will make it add one at the position I want based on my data.  Of course it doesn't work.

```
function countdown(callback) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress'),
    time = 0, max = 100,
    int = setInterval(function() {
        bar.style.width = Math.floor(100 * time++ / max) + '%';
        if (time - 1 == max) {
            clearInterval(int);
            // 600ms - width animation time
            callback && setTimeout(callback, 600);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
function createMarkers() {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress'),
       var pos = "20px";
       m = $("<div class='marker'></div>");
    m.css({"margin-left": pos +'px'});
    bar.appendChild(m)
}
createMarkers()
countdown(function() {

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mrQ3w/147/

Comment: Can you post what work have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make one more div for markers, place the progressbar and marker on top of each other with higher z-index for markers' div.

Here is a basic fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mrQ3w/153/.

```
                  (function(i){
                    for(i;i>0;i--)
                   {createMarkers();}
                  })(4);
```

You need to calculate the *pos* according to your needs, and pass the number of markers according to your need.